# Is it possible to call to main method from a class that already has a main method?

Tags: java

I have a program with two class and each has a main method, i wanted to know if it is possible to call the main method from my second class to work in my first class. I can't seem to find any examples that will help, that makes me think that it's not possible for me to do what I want to.

First Class:

```
    package scannerarrays;

        import java.util.Scanner;

             public class ScannerArrays {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String words;
    int IDnum;


    System.out.println("Enter your Name");
    words = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your Surname");
    words = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your ID number");
    IDnum = input.nextInt();
```

Second Class:

```
 package scannerarrays;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class IdDetails {


String id;
int month[] = {31 , 29 , 31 , 30 , 31, 31 , 30 , 31 , 30 , 31};


public IdDetails()  {


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your ID number \nLike : 000000000V");
    id = input.next();



     }

public int getYear() {
    return(1900 + Integer.parseInt(id.substring(0, 2)));

}
    public int getDays() {
     int d = Integer.parseInt(id.substring(2, 5)); 
     if (d > 500) {
         return (d - 500);
     }else{
         return d;



     }

    }
public void setMonth() {

    int mo = 0, da = 0;
    int days = getDays();

    for (int i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
        if (days < month[i]) {
            mo = i + 1;
            da = days;
            break;

        }else{
            days = days - month[i];
        }        

        }

  System.out.println("Month: " + mo + "\nDate : " + da);

    }

    public String getSex() {
        String M = "Male" , F = "Female";
        int d = Integer.parseInt(id.substring(2 , 5));
        if (d>81) {
            return F;

        }else{
         return M;   
        }

}
     public static void main(String[]args) {

IdDetails ID = new IdDetails();
System.out.println("Your Details of DOB from ID");
System.out.println("Year : " + ID.getYear());
ID.setMonth();
System.out.println("Sex : " + ID.getSex());

      }



     }
```

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args)` is just a method, like all other methods (the JVM just treats it specially when you ask it to run a class)

Comment: Yes you can do it, but it would be worthless to try in this situation. Better to create an IdDetails class that is more "OOP-like", that has no UI (user interface) code within it, and that can be used in the first class. So get that Scanner out of the IdDetails class, give it decent fields, a real constructor (again without that Scanner), and let the other class handle all the UI code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main method is like any other static method of your class, so you can call it the same way, just like:

```
IdDetails.main();
```

Or with any number of String parameters:

```
IdDetails.main("name", "surname", "12");
```

But that seems a litte bit confusing, to use a logic within a main method this way. If you really need to do it, just make another method with fixed input parameters and call it everywhere you need it (in your case in both main methods).